# How to setup Angular 6 progress bar with RxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to make a progress bar show for multiple requests done in an Angular application.
I have gotten the multiple requests to work without the progress bar by using forkJoin, in short this is how I have done:

ArticleService

```
getArticles(articleIds: Array<string>) : Observable<any[]> {
  let apiCalls = [];

  articleIds.forEach(articleId => {
    apiCalls.push(this.http.get(this.uri + '/article/' + articleId));
  });

  return forkJoin(apiCalls);
}
```

Component

```
let articleIds = ['234234', '2343334', '2354345'];

this.articleService.getArticles(articleIds).subscribe(response => {
  response.forEach(responseObj => {
    // Do stuff
  });
});
```

But now I want to do something like in this example: https://www.learnrxjs.io/recipes/progressbar.html

But I'm not sure on how to set it up in my specific case, I have tried this:

ArticleService

```
getArticles(articleIds: Array<string>) : Observable<any[]> {
  let apiCalls = [];

  articleIds.forEach(articleId => {
    apiCalls.push(this.http.get(this.uri + '/article/' + articleId));
  });

  return from(apiCalls).pipe(concatAll());
}
```

But not sure on how to setup it in the component to handle the progress update, preferably something that increments a "this.progress" variable on each completed request.

Anyone that has any ideas or pointers on how to do this?
Should I use "switchMapTo" and where should I have that, in the service or component?
Is there another better approach to handle this, can I tap into forkJoin to get events on each completed request to increment the progress bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in a nutshell you can do something like below, using `merge` you achieve the same effect as forkjoin i.e all run concurrently.

```js
this.percentage = 0
let completed = 0

merge(...apiCalls).pipe(
  tap(res=>this.percentage=(++completed/apiCalls.length))
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, got some minor issues with the scope when adding a callback to update the progress bar so I can have it in a service. But solved it in the subscribe method :)